# rosserial_python Error

Tags: ros, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to connect my arduino with ROS i am following the hello world tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World
i am using ROS Jade

when i come to the step following step:
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0

i receive an error of serial port as:
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1455616377.748461] Error opening serial: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

i know its an error of the serial port but i am not able to solve it plz help me i really need help with this matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226777/rosserial_python-error/) by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-02-17**:
The error says that `/dev/ttyUSB0` does not exist. Did you check if you find this port with `ls /dev/ttyUSB0`? Otherwise, you need to replace `ttyUSB0` with your correct serial port, as it says in the tutorial.

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-02-19**:
thank you but how do I find the correct serial port? I want to use Bluetooth for the communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple way to check the correct serial port is using the Arduino IDE , on the tools menu go to "Port" and it shows the current port where Arduino is connect. Once you check the arduino the `_port:=` param has to be the same

---

Originally posted by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) with karma: 70 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-04-09**:
thank you that solved the problem